# Print set of images in a square mosaic

Tags: r, image, plot

Assume we have a set of identical images `imgs` (see below). Note that the set length may vary in practice.

```
library(magick)
library(rsvg)

img <- image_read_svg("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/132/132233.svg", width = 30)
imgs <- replicate(8, img)
```

[image]

The goal is to print a square image containing all the images within `imgs` (even though the set length may not be a square number):

[image]

I played around with `image_append()` and `image_append(..., stack = TRUE)` from the `magick` package without success [[ref]](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#layers). Ideally I would like a function (e.g. `printMosaic(imgs)`) that takes as input `imgs` and outputs the squared image displayed above. Maybe it would be easier to achieve with a different package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very nice question!

First, lets randomly select how many images we want and then automatically calculate how many rows/columns we will need.

```
# Number of images from 1 to 100
N <- sample(1:1e2, 1)
print(N)
[1] 84
# How many rows/columns we will need
X <- ceiling(sqrt(N))
print(X)
[1] 10
```

Create empty panel using `multipanelfigure` package with `X` rows and columns:

```
library(multipanelfigure)
figure <- multi_panel_figure(columns = X, rows = X)

# Iterate from 1 to N images and append them to figure
for(i in seq_len(N)) {
    # "./R.png" is path to image I'm using
    # With this package you don't need to worry about importing images
    figure %<>% fill_panel("./R.png", label = "", scaling = "shrink")
}
```

[image]